# zend framework with gdata api. access_token expiry

Tags: php, zend-framework, gdata

I have got access_token. 
Using zend framework. I have obtained token for multiple permissions. like gmail inbox feeds, contacts, docs and calendar and google email settings. 
my question is that using three-leged.php. what the maximum life time of access_token.and if my token expires within a limited time. how can i get new token without user interaction.
i am using this [api.](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.gdata.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, the token is "long-lived" and does not expire unless the user changes pertinent account info and/or their password.